# Excel IF statement; 3 arguments - if does not match first row in array, formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been struggling with an excel IF statement with multiple parameters and am hoping someone can help.

I am putting together a table to demonstrate whether a test subject is currently taking part in a study.

I have two tabs: **Test Subjects** & **Study Information**.

The **Test Subjects** tab is laid out as such:

> Test Subject ID | Study ID

The **Study Information** is laid out as such:

> Study ID | Study Start Date | Study End Date

If the Study ID on the Test Subjects tab is equal to the Study ID in the Study information tab, and today's date falls between the Study Start Date and Study End Date, return "Yes". If not, return "No".

The array formulas I have tried only work if the Study ID on the Test Subjects tab is the first one in the list on the Study Information tab. If I switch it to any other Study IDs, I get a false even if the result should be true.

**Failed Formula Examples:**

`L5` is the Study ID on the Test Subjects tab.

`'Study Information'!$B$7:$B$71` is the Study ID range that I am trying to match with.

`'Study Information'!$C$7:$C$71`

```
`Study Information'!$D$7:$D$71` is the study end date.
```

`=IF((L5='Study Information'!$B$7:$B$71)*(TODAY()>='Study Information'!$C$7:$C$71)*(TODAY()<='Study Information'!$D$7:$D$71),"Yes","No")`

Study IDs are alpha numeric. I am not sure if that makes any difference.
I'd appreciate any feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try seeing if a COUNTIFS returns a value > zero.

```
=choose(sign(countifs('Study Information'!B:B, L5, 'Study Information'!C:C, "<="&today(), 'Study Information'!D:D, ">="&today()))+1, "no", "yes")
```

Comment: Just tested and this is working! Very awesome - much appreciated!